# Categories datatype

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I want to check what hobbies a user has and I want to insert it to a database.

I was thinking about making a column Hobbies and to insert the data in a string type in that form : `{"Hobby1", "Hobby2", "Hobby3"}`

But then the code to filter out the hobbies would be big, is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Hobbies` table and insert hobbies into that such as Golf, Photography etc.
Then create a `UserHobby` table to associate a User with a Hobby such that a User can have multiple hobbies.

EG

```
UserID      FirstName       
1           Bob
2           John

HobbyID     HobbyName       
1           Golf
2           Photography     

UserHobbyID UserID  HobbyID 
1           1       1   
2           1       2
3           2       2
```

Comment: Quick google search: http://sqliteman.com/ but a part from that I do not know much about sqllite, sorry.

Comment: If that's the best way to go then it is the best way to go ! Thanks a bunch ! ; )

Comment: Another question, do I really need a relationship in here ? A one-to-one relationship or can I pass on it ?

Comment: Well, if a user only has one hobby, then you can place the hobby into the userstable as you have suggested. but if you envisage a user having more than one hobby, setting up a relationship table that allows a many-to-many is the best way to go about it. otherwise you'll keep needing to make schema changes which is a headache.,

Comment: Every user can have many hobbies. Though I'm going your way and I create them other 2 tables `Hobbies` and `UserHobbies`, but I don't understand why do I need a relationship if I just insert the ID of the user that has the hobbies and then the hobbies that he chose, why would I need a relationship in this case ?

Comment: Where would you put the hobbies against the users if there was no table allowing it? My example above shows why an intermediate table is required. User 1 has 2 hobbies and user 2 has 1 hobby without having to alter the `User` table or `Hobby` table.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, I do add the intermediate table and the key is UserHobbyID, then I just insert to the database the UserID that's logged in and the HobbyID that he chose in for say a for loop. Why is a relationship required ? Maybe a newbie question but I really don't understand.